# What is a countably generated algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What is a countably generated algebra? Can't find a definition online.

Answer (score 1):

It is an algebra with a countable generator. That is, if $\mathcal{A}$ is your algebra, then it admits a countable collection $C$ such that $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}(C)$. Remember that the algebra $\mathcal{A}(C)$ generated by $C$ is the intersection of all algebras containing $C$.

Answer (score 0):

A countably generated algebra is an algebra that is generated by a countable set.  That is, there is a countable set $S$ such that the algebra is the set of all linear combinations (over the field $\mathbb F$ being used) of finite products (in whatever order) of elements of $S$.

Comment: I guess OP is thinking about the other notion of [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets), since he used the `measure-theory` tag... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's an algebra (whatever your definition is) which has countably many generators. Classic examples include

$$K[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots]$$

the polynomial algebra over a field $K.$

If $E/F$ is a finite field extension, then $E$ is a finitely generated $F$ algebra as a $F-$vector space.

The division algebra $\Bbb{H},$ also known as the quaternions, is a $4-$dimensional non-commutative division algebra over $\Bbb{R}.$

Where $$\Bbb{H}=\{a+bi+cj+dk\mid a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{R} \text{ and } i^2=j^2=k^2=-1, ~ ij=k,~ jk=i,~ki=j\}.$$